# What elements can you remove from a dense subset while still keeping it dense?

Tags: general-topology

More formally, if $E$ is a dense subset of $X$, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions that a set $A \subset  E$ must satisfy so that $E-A$ is dense in $X$.

Clearly, it is necessary that $A$ does not contain any open set but I haven't found any sufficient conditions.

Comment: Look into the definition of a "nowhere dense set."  It seems that A being nowhere dense as a subspace of E is barking up the right tree.